# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined: how to get my data array field

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing

[image]

```
{clients ? console.log(clients.clients.clients.data) : null}
```

This code display data that you see on the image. But if I try make

```
{clients ? console.log(clients.clients.clients.data) : null}
```

I got TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. How to get my array in data field?

Comment: `{clients ? console.log(clients.clients.clients.data) : null}` == `{clients ? console.log(clients.clients.clients.data) : null}` ? Same line twice?

Comment: Yea, thanks, It's my error I fix it

Comment: sounds like you have an asynchronous issue here

Answer (score 0):

I found soulution:

```
{clients.clients.clients ? console.log(clients.clients.clients.data) : null}
```

But I don't understand why this work next way

Answer (score -1):

if your returned jSn is

```
clients={data:[{}],meta:{}}
```

then

```
{data: Array(1), meta: {…}}
console.log(clients.data);
```

Output

> ```
> VM257:1 [{…}]0: {}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
> undefined
> ```